# Cool down for command and certain day run command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I wrote code for this bot and I want it to do two things:

1. Have a cooldown for 15 min
2. Have a command that only works on Friday.

I am new to coding so the discord documentation did not help.

**My imports**:

```
import discord, asyncio, time, discord.guild, random, os, youtube_dl
import os
import asyncio
import math
import random
import youtube_dl
import datetime
import json
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, guild_only
from itertools import cycle
```

**Code for the 15 minutes cool down**:

```
@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    user = ctx.author

    earn = random.randrange(6900)

    await ctx.send(f'Someone gave you {earn} coins!')


    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earn

    with open('main code\economy.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users,f)
```

**Code for the command that works on only Friday**:

```
@client.command()
async def friday(ctx):
    vid = '<URL>'
    
    await ctx.send(vid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 15 minutes cooldown

Use [@commands.cooldown()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 900, commands.BucketType.user)  # 15 minutes is 900 seconds
async def command_with_cooldown(ctx):
    ...  # code

@command_with_cooldown.error
async def cooldown_error_handler(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send("You can only use this command once every 15 minutes!")
```

#### Only fridays

Use [datetime.datetime.today().weekday()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday)

```py
import datetime

@client.command()
async def friday_command(ctx):
    if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 4:  # 0 is monday, 6 is sunday
        ...  # code
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can only use this command on fridays!")
```